# Will these parts be compatible together?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, cpu, motherboard, sata

I am looking to build a PC that is meant just for gaming and programming. If I go through with it, it will be my first PC build ever. I've watched a few videos to learn how to build a computer and picked my parts carefully. I'm mostly concerned because I have seen people get all the parts and assemble them all and it didn't boot/work due to a compatibility issue.

Part list:

- CPU: Intel Core i7 4790k
- Video Card: Asus Radeon R9 390 8GB GDDR5
- CPU Cooler: Cooler Master Hyper 212 EVO
- Motherboard: MSI Z97 Gaming 5
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance 16GB DDR3-1600MHZ
- PSU: Corsair RM1000 Modular Power Supply 1000W
- CD Drive: Samsung 24x Internal SATA
- Thermal Compound: Artic Silver 5
- HDMI Cable: Inland 6ft 24k Gold Plated Premium High Speed HDMI Cable
- Monitor: AOC E2425SWD 24"
- Case: Corsair Obsidian 750D
- OS: Windows 8.1 64 Bit
- Hybrid Drive: Seagate 4TB SSHD Sata III
- Sata Cable: 18" SATA Data Connecter

Just note, I am not looking for a shopping recommendation, I am merely looking to see if my parts will work together.

Comment: The parts are based along a recommendation a regular on Newegg Fourms gave me. He posted it on PCPartPicker and it didn't come up with any incompatibilities. I did the same thing on that site with the parts I picked and it said no issues found. I'm more worried about the PSU, the CPU, the motherboard, and the video card.

Comment: This is as far off-topic as it gets. Neither the question nor answer would be of any use to anyone else, ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On paper these parts are all compatible. 
The motherboard is supports 16GB @ 1600MHZ RAM, is able to house and overclock your 4790k, and has enough slots for your SATA needs. It also has correct PCI-E x16 slots to house a R9 390.
The power supply can supply enough power for your system needs and has the correct pinout for the motherboard ATX and CPU.

Comment: Thank you Ben Sampica. These are the main parts I was worried about with a compatibility issue. Your post is accepted as an answer.